# SQL Group By Ignoring Wildcard Character '%'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to achieve a query where I have this data.

```
A%
A%%
A%%%
A%%%%%
A%%%%%
B%%%
B%%%
```

I want to group them by and ignoring the wildcard character %,
The output I expect from this query is like this.

```
A
B
```

Comment: use [translate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just strip off the `%` characters and then aggregate:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(val, '%', '') AS val
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard string **REPLACE** function and group by column you wanted:

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(yourColumnName, '%', '')
FROM
    yourTable
GROUP BY
    REPLACE(yourColumnName, '%', '')
```

Comment: This works, but using `DISTINCT` would feel more natural. We use `GROUP BY` rather when we want to use aggregation functions (`MIN`, `COUNT`, ...), too. This makes your query look like there might be a mistake made. No big deal, but when debugging production code, such query may have people wonder and slow down the debugging process.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner agreed. DISTINCT is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL 2017 14.x and later version you can use, [Translate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

SELECT TRANSLATE('A%%%', '%', '')

output will be A.